# Parse data from page 1 to page 2 using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Good day,

I have a problem parsing data using `href` get method to php retrieve by ajax to another page. Is it possible? btw I'm using *CODEIGNITER*.

**Here's my html href code:**

```
<a href="'.base_url().'homeadmin/view/page_user_profile/user_profile? user_id='.$key->user_id.'" class="btn btn-outline purple">   <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> View</a>
```

**Here's my PHP code parsing the id after button click:**

```
function user_profile()
{
    $user_id = $this->input->get('user_id');
    $sql = $this->crud->getData("tbl_user as u,tbl_group as g, tbl_sub_group as sg, tbl_user_permission as up, tbl_user_profile as p", "u.user_id='$user_id' AND u.user_group_id=g.group_id AND u.user_sub_group_id = sg.sub_group_id AND up.user_user_perm ='$user_id' AND u.user_id = p.profile_id")['rows'];
    echo json_encode($sql);
}
```

**Then this is my ajax code:**

```
function user_profile()
{
    $.get(baseurl + 'homeadmin/user_profile', {}, function(data) {
        var result = eval('(' + data + ')');
        $('#user_name_profile').html(result[0].user_username);
    })
}
```

**Here is what should be the output:**

```
<h1 class="font-green sbold uppercase" id="user_name_profile"></h1>
```

I hope someone will correct me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the button to the function `user_profile()`:

```js
$( "a.btn" ).bind( "click", user_profile );
```

No need to define the href attribute. More information on binding [here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

The empty object of your `$.get()` invocation inside the function should be `{user_id: $key->user_id}`. Make sure `$key` is available in the scope of the function.

Comment: so i will use onClick('user_id') then send data to php function?

Comment: Essentially. Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp). You will have to figure out how to pass user_id to the function you're binding to the click event.

Comment: but the output result should be in the another page.

Comment: Got it. Then you don't need to bind to the click event. All you have to do is extract user_id from `window.location.href` when the new page loads and provide it as `{user_id: user_id_from_href}` to the get request. Then user_id will be available to the PHP function.

Comment: can you provide an example pleaseeee .. same as my project above. :)